# Trying to create a 'close' option using js, having trouble with the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement the image viewing mechanics from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ to my website.

I'm looking towards doing what this website did with the 2nd house image from 'Different effects' section. (Just viewing and closing, no scrolling or next button).

I tried putting the .css and html code from that website into my code and attached the necessary image, .css and .js files but it still doesn't work at all.

html code:

```
        <a class="fancybox-effects-b" href="demo/5_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit">
<img src="demo/5_b.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how to go on about implementing this? I spent nearly 2 hours trying this and still can't seem to figure this out...

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:

This is my html code:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="heading">Photoshop</div>
    <div class="content2">
        <div id="featured" class="clearfix grid_12">
            <ul>
                <li>    <a class="fancybox-effects-b" href="images/sadMiddle.jpg"  target="_blank">
                <span>Middle of your heart</span><img  src="images/sadMiddle.jpg" alt="Middle" /></a></a>
            </li>
            <li>    <a href="images/sadLeft.jpg">
                    <span>Left the heart</span>
                    <img src="images/sadLeft.jpg" alt="Left" />
                </a>

            </li>
            <li>    <a href="images/sadRight.jpg">
                    <span>Right mind & heart</span>
                <img src="images/sadRight.jpg" alt="Right" />
                </a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

(I'm testing it on the first image only right now)

JS that I've added in:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<
script type = "text/javascript"
src = "lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" > < /script>


    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="
text / javascript " src="
source / jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="
stylesheet " type="
text / css " href="
source / jquery.fancybox.css" media="
screen " />

    <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
    <link rel="
stylesheet " type="
text / css " href="
source / helpers / jquery.fancybox - buttons.css ? v = 1.0.5 " />
    <script type="
text / javascript " src="
source / helpers / jquery.fancybox - buttons.js ? v = 1.0.5 "></script>

<script type="
text / javascript ">
   $(function() {
        $(".fancybox - effects - b ").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });
   });
</script>
```

css file:

```
/*! fancyBox v2.1.4 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
    position: relative;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
    z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
    color: #444;
    font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url(fancybox_sprite.png);
}

#fancybox-loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    background-position: 0 -108px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    right: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99999px;
    left: -99999px;
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 99999px;
    max-height: 99999px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 8050;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

(I'm assuming most of these are useless except the one that contains 'fancybox_sprite.png' which is a image for close button).

EDIT 2: (Could I mix the javascript together?)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         maxWidth: 800,
         maxHeight: 600,
         fitToView: false,
         autoResize: true,
         closeClick: false,
         openEffect: 'elastic',
         closeEffect: 'elastic'
     });
 });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showhide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.roundabout-1.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(document).ready(function() { //Start up our Featured Project Carosuel
            $('#featured ul').roundabout({
                easing: 'easeOutInCirc',
                duration: 600
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is not working? did you check the browser console to see whether there is any error?

Comment: the javascript implemented doesn't function at all. only the html it seems... :(

Comment: your src urls of scirpt are wrong, there are lot of spaces and other things

Comment: like jquery script should be `<script type = "text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: don't put new line character or spaces in the `src` attribute of `link` and `script` elements

Answer (score 1):

jQuery library must be included before fancybox

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".fancybox").fancybox({
             maxWidth: 800,
             maxHeight: 600,
             fitToView: false,
             autoResize: true,
             closeClick: false,
             openEffect: 'elastic',
             closeEffect: 'elastic'
         });
     });
 </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showhide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.roundabout-1.0.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function() { //Start up our Featured Project Carosuel
        $('#featured ul').roundabout({
            easing: 'easeOutInCirc',
            duration: 600
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that! no invalid spaces in the actual coding through my dreamweaver though. hmm.

Comment: can you inspect the page with developer tools to see whether the script files are getting downloaded

Comment: I think it could be the fact that I'm using another script file for iamge scroller? Is there a way to mix these two together? I'll show you the javascript code that are attached in the beginning of my HTML file.

Comment: @user2320517 got the problem  the jquery library must be include before fancy box library

Comment: yes, that works fine. here's the screencapture of the image scroller: http://postimg.org/image/t1zmusl0p/

Comment: Hmm. How does that work? Do I place the code in order? or inside the existing jquery library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2320517 see my answer and the order in which the scripts are added

Comment: both the scroller and the image viewer (fancybox) javascript doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in the header , then you need to enclose it in  `DOM ready handler`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        // Your code here
   });
</script>
```

Also make sure you are including the plugin after you include jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Either you put your JS code at the end or wrap it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
})
```

If possible please put complete HTML so I can get a better idea.

Comment: added, I'll add other stuffs necessarily to fix this if you request. thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/hyPPp/) that may help you out.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         maxWidth: 800,
         maxHeight: 600,
         fitToView: false,
         autoResize: true,
         closeClick: false,
         openEffect: 'elastic',
         closeEffect: 'elastic'
     });
 });
```

Comment: Still doesn't work sadly. Is it because it's inside a content that javascript isn't functioning properly? I edited in the working example you provided here but it still acts like the code is <a href="sadMiddle.jpg"> which is just viewing the image.

Comment: @user2320517 have you tried plugging your images into the jsFiddle example I set up? Just a thought, are you using more than one jquery plugin on your page? It could be a simple library conflict.

Comment: @user2320517 You may want to try using the full urls for your libraries and images.

Comment: Hi, I edited out to apply my images and copied exactly as you wrote and tried it out. Both times, it doesn't work. If you don't mind, can you have a look at my full html and css code? I'll edit it in to this thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In regards to the library conflict. Yes, I'm using another javascript for image scroll. Could that be the reason? I'll show you the javascript code in the thread.